# input type="tel" for opera mini is not working. can any one guide me please

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

input type="tel" is not working for opera mini browser. Can any please solve this issue.

Thanks for your kindness

Comment: That type of input is not supported in opera mini: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url. You'd need to use a masking plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Please check **[URL](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-email-tel-url)**, [**Another one**](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

`The tel type is currently supported only in Safari 8.`

Comment: but i had seen some websites in which this input type works in opera mini

Comment: Can you give us example

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here http://caniuse.com/#search=tel the input type="tel" is not supported by Opera Mini and IE 8, you can't do a lot on it, an option would be creating a keyboard (made of HTML and javascript) to allow Opera Mini users to easy input the telephone number and store it into a simple input type="text", but before starting I think you should check how many Opera Mini users you will have, since in some countries Opera Mini usage is < than 1%, and without support they will simply have to perform two or three additional steps when using their keyboard...

Comment: Thank you Mr. Andrea . That was a better option

Comment: Also I have a doubt that does this input type work in ucmini browser??

Comment: UC mini has a very restricted support for input types (as you can see here http://quirksmode.org/html5/inputs/mobile.html), for everything that is not supported however you can always use javascript+html, I don't know what browser your users use, but in my projects I simply don't support not so famous browsers such as UC mini :)

Comment: Where do can I find the guidelines to develop a website that look responsive in UCMINI browser even if the speed mode is enabled.
?